# Windows 10, GDB Configure command fails for build operation

Tags: windows, build, gdb

What am I missing below (path, environment variable, ?)  running from a Windows Command Prompt window.

See “gdb-7.12\configure' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.” below:

C:\Users\_gerlad0_\Downloads\Installables\gdb-7.12\build>C:\Users\_gerlad0_\Downloads\Installables\gdb-7.12\configure
'C:\Users\_gerlad0_\Downloads\Installables\gdb-7.12\configure' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\_gerlad0_\Downloads\Installables\gdb-7.12\build>set path
Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\5.4 2016q2\bin\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
      C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;
      C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
      C:\Program Files (x86)\NTRU Cryptosystems\NTRU TCG Software Stack\bin\;
      C:\Program Files\NTRU Cryptosystems\NTRU TCG Software Stack\bin\;
      C:\Program Files\Wave Systems Corp\Gemalto\Access Client\v5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;
      c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;
      C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile.dnx\bin;
      C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;
      C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\cygwin64\bin
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC

Thanks for any insight!!

Comment: Run configure from unix shell (from cygwin/mingw).

Comment: Thanks dbrank0, looks like I need to improve my reading comprehension! 
((How do I mark this as answered?))

Comment: I have written a short answer which you can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most [configure scripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configure_script) are written for the unix shell(s).

You need to run configure from such unix shell (bash for example), which you should get from cygwin/mingw/msys package for your windows.

Comment: Help indicates that a colored check mark next to an answer marks it as "accepted".  I don't see the check mark!!  How do I accept??